# Check if data is returned Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        Username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
        Tweet = all_data["text"]
        Location = all_data["place"]["name"]
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Tweets (Username, Tweet, Location) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                  (Username, Tweet, Location))
```

I have set up a StreamListener to follow a specified Twitter account. Whenever a Tweet is posted, the username, tweet and location are retrieved and stored into an sql database. The problem I'm encountering is if no location is present then the program fails. Is there anyway to check a location value is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use a try/except

```
try:
   Location = all_data["place"]["name"]
except KeyError:
   Location = "anywhere"
```